# Error Logging FoxPro vs .Net

Tags: .net, logging

Back in the day -- Fred Flintstone was still in shorts -- in FoxPro, you could STORE everything in memory to a MEMO field in a table with a single command.
I don't know about other practical uses, nor the wisdom of it, but I loved to use it when 'AirdisplacementDevice Implements ManureSpreader' : when an error occurred you'd store the memory in the memo field.
You could then use RESTORE FROM, load the stored memory and re-enact the event in all it's gory detail and start debugging.
I was wondering, is there an 'easy' way to do that in .Net ?

Answer (score 0):

Net exactly, but you can use reflection to get details about properties and such and you can get access from the stack trace. I'm not aware of any way to stash away current state and then some how load these values when debugging.